# SAS Code for dynamic date

Tags: sas-macro

Currently I am working on a project in sas. We are producing the reports based on data from November2015. I need to import that file which has name //consumer accounting/Reports/SAS Reports/20151130/M0ED1 for November data. Next month it will be //consumer accounting/Reports/SAS Reports/20151231/M0ED2 and then next month it will be the same instead of it will have the data from 20160130 and M0ED3. 
I am trying to write a code that it will directly import the file with the correct name so that i don't need to write the file name manually every time i try to prepare a report.
Please suggest me the way. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

```
/*Set How many months ago the data you are looking at is*/
%let numMonths = 6;
/*Set which Year and Month was report 1*/
%let firstReport = '15NOV2015'd;


 data _null_;
 /*Get Todays Date*/
 format mydate myreportdate date9.;
 myDate = today();
 /*Go Back the number of months set in the Macro variable. 
   As you want the last day of that month, add back on 1 month and then remove a day*/
 myReportDate = intnx('month',myDate,-&numMonths.+1)-1;
 /*Calculate which report number this is using the INTCK Function to count the number of months ends crossed between 2 dates*/
 myRunNumber = compress(put(INTCK('MONTH',&firstReport.,myReportDate)+1,best12.));
 /*Create A String with the location and name of your report*/
 myReportString = "//consumer accounting/Reports/SAS Reports/"||
                      put(year(myReportDate),z4.)||
                      put(month(myReportDate),z2.)||
                      put(day(myReportDate),z2.)||
                      "/M0ED"||myRunNumber;
 /*Create a macro variable with the location and name of your report*/
 call symputx('myReport',myReportString);
run;

/*Output the macro variable to the log*/
%put &myReport.;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But still I have one problem. When I use mydate= today(); and run the other I get M0EOD1 as desired. When I put mydate='15Jun2016'd; I get M0EOD2 as desired, But when I put as mydate='15Jul2016'd, I get M0EOD91 but I was expecting M0EOD3. Also when I put mydate='15Aug2016'd I get M0EOD92. Can anyone tell me where is the issue?

Comment: Hi shankar,I'm afraid I didn't have SAS in front of me when I wrote this answer, and thus a mistake crept in! I've edited my code to use the intck function instead, which calculates the difference between 2 dates - in this case I've set it to calculate the difference in terms of months. If this now answers your question can please give me a green tick!